# How to avoid a created branch to be build in Jenkins?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket

In our team we create branches with a Bitbucket integration through JIRA. Thus, the branches are pushed to Bitbucket and then usually checked out by a developer to work on.

The push to Bitbucket triggers a build of the branch in Jenkins. This build is unnecessary as it builds the latest commit of the base branch which has already been build. How can we avoid/skip this build? We're use declarative pipelines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Multi-Branch Pipeline Job, if you are using Bitbucket Plugin https://plugins.jenkins.io/cloudbees-bitbucket-branch-source/ for Branch Sources, then there is a way which can help to not trigger Jenkins job when a new Branch is created.

Install Basic Branch Build Strategies Plugin https://plugins.jenkins.io/basic-branch-build-strategies/. Installing this provides an option in Bitbucket Plugin to skip first execution.
[image]

By this the initial execution done during branch creation can be skipped.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Jenkins CasC and bitbucket.  organizationFolder is like multibranchPipeline and you have this option using DSL

```
organizationFolder --> properties --> suppressFolderAutomaticTriggering
```

Full Example

```
organizationFolder('Infrastructure/Company/infrastructure-vpn-account') {
  description('Repositories inside Infrastructure - VPN Account Project')
  displayName('Infrastructure - VPN Account')
  organizations {
    bitbucket {
      repoOwner('MyOrganization')
      credentialsId('bitbucket-oauth-credentials')
      autoRegisterHooks(false)
      // "Traits" ("Behaviors" in the GUI) that are "declarative-compatible"
      traits {
        submoduleOptionTrait {
          extension {
            disableSubmodules(false)
            recursiveSubmodules(true)
            trackingSubmodules(false)
            reference(null)
            timeout(null)
            parentCredentials(true)
          }
        }
        projectKeyRegexFilter {
            // A Java regular expression to restrict the repositories belonging to a Bitbucket project.
            regex('IVA')
        }
        bitbucketBranchDiscovery {
          // Determines which branches are discovered.
          strategyId(3)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  properties {
    suppressFolderAutomaticTriggering {
        // Defines a regular expression of branch names which will be triggered automatically, for example (?!
        branches("")
        // Determines events for which branches with matched names should not be triggered automatically.
        // Possible values for value:
        //     'INDEXING'
        //     'EVENTS'
        //     'NONE'
        strategy('INDEXING')
    }
  }
  // "Project Recognizers"
  projectFactories {
    workflowMultiBranchProjectFactory {
      scriptPath 'Jenkinsfile'
    }
  }
  // "Orphaned Item Strategy"
  orphanedItemStrategy {
    discardOldItems {
      daysToKeep(10)
      numToKeep(10)
    }
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D94Ib.png)